# Error Inflating class android.widget.Switch

Tags: java, android, eclipse, preferenceactivity

I am very confused cause it works well if I create the PreferenceActivity in a new project but it's not work if I create it in my current project.
I am sure my SDK version is over 14.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

The code is auto-created by eclipse.

```
package com.example.cornerstorepos;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceCategory;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.preference.RingtonePreference;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * A {@link PreferenceActivity} that presents a set of application settings. On
 * handset devices, settings are presented as a single list. On tablets,
 * settings are split by category, with category headers shown to the left of
 * the list of settings.
 * <p>
 * See <a href="http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html">
 * Android Design: Settings</a> for design guidelines and the <a
 * href="http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html">Settings
 * API Guide</a> for more information on developing a Settings UI.
 */
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    /**
     * Determines whether to always show the simplified settings UI, where
     * settings are presented in a single list. When false, settings are shown
     * as a master/detail two-pane view on tablets. When true, a single pane is
     * shown on tablets.
     */
    private static final boolean ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS = false;

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setupSimplePreferencesScreen();
}

/**
 * Shows the simplified settings UI if the device configuration if the
 * device configuration dictates that a simplified, single-pane UI should be
 * shown.
 */
private void setupSimplePreferencesScreen() {
    if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
        return;
    }

    // In the simplified UI, fragments are not used at all and we instead
    // use the older PreferenceActivity APIs.

    // Add 'general' preferences.
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

    // Add 'notifications' preferences, and a corresponding header.
    PreferenceCategory fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_notifications);
    getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);

    // Add 'data and sync' preferences, and a corresponding header.
    fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_data_sync);
    getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);

    // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences to
    // their values. When their values change, their summaries are updated
    // to reflect the new value, per the Android Design guidelines.
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    return isXLargeTablet(this) && !isSimplePreferences(this);
}

/**
 * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
 * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
 */
private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
}

/**
 * Determines whether the simplified settings UI should be shown. This is
 * true if this is forced via {@link #ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS}, or the device
 * doesn't have newer APIs like {@link PreferenceFragment}, or the device
 * doesn't have an extra-large screen. In these cases, a single-pane
 * "simplified" settings UI should be shown.
 */
private static boolean isSimplePreferences(Context context) {
    return ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS
            || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
            || !isXLargeTablet(context);
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }
}

/**
 * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
 * to reflect its new value.
 */
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference
                    .setSummary(index >= 0 ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
            // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
            // using RingtoneManager.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

            } else {
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                if (ringtone == null) {
                    // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                    preference.setSummary(null);
                } else {
                    // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                    // name.
                    String name = ringtone
                            .getTitle(preference.getContext());
                    preference.setSummary(name);
                }
            }

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
 * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
 * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
 * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
 * dependent on the type of preference.
 * 
 * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
 */
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference
            .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(
            preference,
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                    preference.getContext()).getString(preference.getKey(),
                    ""));
}

/**
 * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends
        PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows data and sync preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
    }
}
```

}

Here is the XML code.

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="example_checkbox"
    android:summary="@string/pref_description_social_recommendations"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_social_recommendations" />
 <SwitchPreference
            android:key="checkbox_preference"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_social_recommendations"        />

<!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference accepts EditText attributes. -->
<!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
<EditTextPreference
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default_display_name"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:key="example_text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_display_name" />

<!--
     NOTE: Hide buttons to simplify the UI. Users can touch outside the dialog to
     dismiss it.
-->
<!-- NOTE: ListPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="-1"
    android:entries="@array/pref_example_list_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_example_list_values"
    android:key="example_list"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_add_friends_to_messages" />
```

This is the error message.

```
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.Switch
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.preference.Preference.onCreateView(Preference.java:536)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:507)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:330)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2360)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1883)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:716)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:777)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1699)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2161)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14123)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1673)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1444)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14123)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:464)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14123)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1673)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1444)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14123)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1673)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1662)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1446)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14123)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1673)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1444)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14123)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:464)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14123)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1673)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1444)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14123)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:464)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14123)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2183)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1947)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-18 16:35:33.377: E/AndroidRuntime(28815):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Loope
```

Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html

```
Since: API Level 14
```

The Switch widget was introduced in ICS.

Source:

[Erorr inflating class switch, ActionBarSherlock (InflateException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961337/erorr-inflating-class-switch-actionbarsherlock-inflateexception)